# Is there a relationship between $p, d, f, d$... orbitals and $p, d$... block elements?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, orbitals

In the **quantum mechanical model** of an atom there are various **orbitals** around the nucleus as:
$p$ orbitals, $s$ orbitals, $f$ orbital, $d$ orbital etc.

And in the **periodic table** there are p block elements, f block elements,  d block elements  etc.

As the variables used in the both cases are the same, is there any scientific relationship between this?

Comment: The elements are placed in the block corresponding to the orbital the last electron was filled in. But rigorously speaking, The orbitals are not really "around" the nucleus and the electrons are not really "filled" in the orbitals. The s,p,d,f orbitals are merely the probability distribution of finding an electron at a particular point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in s-block, the outermost electron is in the s-orbit. Same for f and d-block. In p-block too, the valence electron is in the p-orbit for most elements. But there's an exception– for Helium the valence electron is in the s-subshell. But this is only an anomaly as helium is more similar to the inert gases than the Akali Earth metals and so helium is placed in 18th group.